# Why does this constant-Q transform "lose octaves"?

Tags: fft

In [this paper](http://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/arg/klap/schoerkhuber-JAES-2013.pdf) (Schörkhuber, Klapuri, Sontacchi), it's shown that the constant Q-transform evaluated "octave-wise" produces the following looking graph:

[image]

I don't understand why the octaves are "disappearing" in some time intervals. 
Isn't this then a lossy" process somehow?

In the paper it says that this is achieved because

> the atom hop sizes $H_k$ are set according to the highest frequency bin within each octave, that is, for each octave down $H_k$ is multiplied by 2

Comment: The hop size has nothing to do with "accuracy" here. It is chosen to keep the bandwidth-time product constant for collections of 12 bands per octave. That is why all 12 bands the bandwidth halves compared to the preceding 12 bands-block, and the time support doubles.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I don't get it. What does "bandwidth-time product" mean? Why is it kept that way? What does "time support doubles" mean?

Comment: Sorry, it's 8 bands, not 12. I got the 12 from the other paper in the other question you posted. Bandwidth-time product is the product of the bandwidth of a filter and the time support, and it's constant for constant Q filters. Time support is the duration for which a function of time is non-zero, or in a slightly weaker sense, does not decay faster than any polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower frequency atoms are longer in time (or of a length roughly proportional to the period of the frequency, give or take 2X).  So less of these lower frequency atoms are needed per second to cover that time period.  And more of the shorter atoms (for shorter wavelength frequencies) are required for about the same coverage (or with roughly the same percentage overlap).

And to maintain a nearly constant Q, the length of a bandpass FIR filter ends up roughly proportional to some constant multiple of the wavelength of the center bandpass frequency of that filter.

Comment: Yeah "atom" is the proper word here. The dots are individual CQTs. That's why they allow for the variation of computation techniques (the way the "grid of dots" is filled).